# Spark convert TimestampType to String of format yyyyMMddHHmm

Tags: scala, apache-spark, timestamp, datetime-format, datetime-conversion

In my dataframe I have a column of TimestampType format of '2019-03-16T16:54:42.968Z' I would like to convert this to a StringType column with a format of '201903161654' instead of a generic timestamp column.  This is because I need to partition several directories based on the string formatted timestamp, if I partition on the timestamp column it creates special characters when creating the directory.

Is there any api I can use in spark to convert the Timestamp column to a string type with the format above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `date_format` function: `date_format(date/timestamp/string ts, string fmt)`.

Converts a date/timestamp/string to a value of string in the format specified by the date format `fmt`. Supported formats are [Java SimpleDateFormat formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). The second argument `fmt` should be constant. Example: `date_format('2015-04-08', 'y')` is `"2015"`.

Comment: As a note since this is not a complete answer, it really should be 'yyyyMMddHHmm' as the date format filter, not just 'yMdH', this has a completely different output in certain circumstances.

Comment: The example above comes straight from the Hive documentation, which is what Spark's compatibility is based on. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF But, yes, you are absolutely right: one has to carefully read the Java formats docs to pick the right one.

Answer (score 3):

Using unix_timestamp and date_format functions

```
scala> val dt = Seq("2019-03-16T16:54:42.968Z").toDF("ts_str")
dt: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ts_str: string]

scala> dt.select(unix_timestamp('ts_str,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")).show
+----------------------------------------------------+
|unix_timestamp(ts_str, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z')|
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                          1552735482|
+----------------------------------------------------+


scala> dt.select(date_format(unix_timestamp('ts_str,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").cast("timestamp"), "yyyyMMddHHmm").as("res") ).show
+------------+
|         res|
+------------+
|201903161654|
+------------+


scala>
```

or just using to_timestamp and date_format functions

```
scala> val dt = Seq("2019-03-16T16:54:42.968Z").toDF("ts_str")
dt: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ts_str: string]

scala> dt.withColumn("ts_str",to_timestamp('ts_str,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")).show(false)
+-------------------+
|ts_str             |
+-------------------+
|2019-03-16 16:54:42|
+-------------------+


scala> dt.withColumn("ts_str",date_format(to_timestamp('ts_str,"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"), "yyyyMMddHHmm" )).show(false)
+------------+
|ts_str      |
+------------+
|201903161654|
+------------+


scala>
```